# AUTO_INCREMENT lastInsertId - mine or servers'?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I found some related readings on AUTO_INCREMENT on the net and wanted to ask you guys a few things.

Here's a bit of code that I found related to AUTO_INCREMENT inserting. I was not sure if the field is auto_increment if I should skip it in PDO syntax when inserting, or mention it and set it NULL, because it will AUTO_INCREMENT anyways.

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ADDRESS (ADD_ID, ADD_TEXT) VALUES(NULL, 'some address value');

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_DETAILS (NAME, ADD_ID, GENDER, PHONE_NO)
VALUES ('James Bond', LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'MALE', 007);
```

Now, my question is :

1. LAST_INSERT_ID() or PDO's PDO::lastInsertID ($dbh->lastInsertId();) is really the last AUTO_INCREMENT id that i've done, or is it the last AUTO_INCREMENT that the server has done ? (keeping in mind that when I call the function, another say 50 inserts have already completed, and the lastInsertID is now different.....so is it my last insert or the server's last insert.

Thanks a lot,
really appreciate your knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` is connection specific, not server specific.

Hence it'll always relate to the last insert *you* did.

Comment: thanks, that was what i wanted to know....so i can use it as valid my last insert it to insert it in another table as reference to my inserted row, no matter of other recent activity on server. thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Autoincrement will autoincrement from the previous value, or use the value your input, so you can chose to set the ID or let the database pick the ID, and the `last_insert_id()` returns the last inserted id from that connection, automatic or manual set, doesn't matter

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to use the manual method. After all the whole concept is for the IDs to be unique. But using `last_insert_id()` is correct.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but I know by experience that people will try to fill the deleted id's gaps manually, beginners (as I did xD) kind of think of the autoincrement id as a counter, which is wrong.

Comment: Forgot to mention that IDs might be printed on forms etc and therefore have historical value. i.e. imagine a bank reusing your account number and all that hassle that might occur.

Comment: Yeah totally agree, that's why now GUID's are my friends :D

Answer (score 0):

It will be the last id the server gave to a query you executed. So after an insert you want to fetch it before another insert is done by the same script.

Also, just leave the autoincrement field out when working with pdo. Including it and setting it to a specific value might hinder autoincrement to work correctly.

Comment: "after an insert you want to fetch it.." - what do you mean? i simply fetch it with last_insert_id or PDO::'s function, right ? I will fiddle with auto_increment stuff this weekend, get it workin :) thanks bro